# Switching regulator for 40~80V

Tags: voltage-regulator

If I have only +-5v source, can I boost it up to +-80V ?  If possible, can you recommend a part?

If not possible, how should I combine multiple booster to make it to high voltages.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  5 volts can be boosted up to 80 volts fairly simply using a boost converter. Try looking on linear technology's website. They have a great tool where you specify input voltage range, output voltage and output current required. In your case the input voltage range might be 4.5 to 5.5 volts and only you know how much current the 80 volt output is to provide. Also check out flyback converters too. TI have similar offerings.